# A Question about Hessian of log function (general form)

Tags: derivatives

[image]

Sincerely hope to ask how to obtain the RHS?

Should I consider ln(10) among the process of d(log(x))/dx?

Thanks!

Comment: That is just a direct computation. Think of this as a matrix equality and check each entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can avoid computing the components of the Hessian individually by using the multivariable chain and product rules.

I'll assume that $f$ is differentiable and positive on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$.
Let $g(x) = \log f(x)$ for all $x \in \Omega$.  By the chain rule, 
\begin{equation}
g'(x) = f(x)^{-1} f'(x).
\end{equation}
(Note that $f'(x)$ is a $1 \times N$ row vector.)

It follows that 
\begin{align}
\nabla g(x) &= g'(x)^T \\
&= f(x)^{-1} \nabla f(x).
\end{align}

The Hessian of $g$ is given by $\nabla^2 g(x) = q'(x)$, where $q(x) = \nabla g(x)$.
The product rule and the chain rule tell us that
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 g(x) &= q'(x) \\
&= -f(x)^{-2} \nabla f(x) \nabla f(x)^T + f(x)^{-1} \nabla^2 f(x).
\end{align}